# local user from different domain wants to access share without credentials

Tags: windows, file-sharing, shared-folders

- fileserver1 (server2012) is joined on domain1 and hosts a shared folder, named share1
- share1 has sharing & security permissions set to 'Everyone' (Full Control).
- computer1 (win11) is joined on domain2 and is logged-in with a **local** user, named user1.

user1 wants to access share1 but gets a password prompt, and has to use domain1 credentials to access the share.

Is it possible for user1 to access share1 directly, without using any credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible for user1 to access share1 directly, without using any credentials?

No. Even "Everyone" is limited to authenticated users only – even clients in the same domain1 (using their domain accounts) are accessing the share using their implicit domain credentials via Kerberos, not with "no credentials".

A local account, regardless of the machine's domain membership, defaults to sending its local credentials via NTLM – which are accepted if the server has a corresponding local account as well. If there's no matching account on the server, the client must specify some custom credentials that would work.

(The local account *can* specify domain credentials when prompted – you could create an account on domain1 for that purpose. If you specify the username as `user@REALM`, it will even use Kerberos.)

Answer (score 0):

Accessing a share in Windows requires two sets of credentials :

1. The share permissions
2. The folder permissions.

You have set the *share permissions* to 'Everyone' (Full Control),
so the first requirement was fulfilled and user1 was permitted
to *try to access* the underlying folder.

However, the user1 account on computer1 is unknown on the
file-server, so user1 was asked to identify himself with an account
that is known by the file-server.
Once identified, the server could evaluate whether the
specified account had permissions on the folder, and which permissions.

This system of double-permissions is the normal way that shares work under
Windows.

Comment: It’s not even double permissions, “everyone”, is all users on the machine not literally everyone on every machine.

Comment: @Ramhound: True, Everyone includes all users who have logged in with a password, but, also built-in, non-password protected accounts such as `Guest` and `LOCAL_SERVICE`.